# When does a site give rise to a Hausdorff topos

Tags: topos-theory, ct.category-theory

What conditions on a Grothendieck site $\left(C,J\right),$ are equivalent to the diagonal map $$Sh_J\left(C\right) \to Sh_J\left(C\right) \times Sh_J\left(C\right)$$ being a proper map of topoi?

Answer (score 3):

I think Johnstone's Elephant gives a site characterisation of proper maps between toposes; so I guess the problem reduces to finding the site corresponding to the product $Sh_J (C) \times Sh_J(C)$ - this is surely known?

Comment: A completely random guess: is it the coproduct $C \coprod C$?

Comment: No the coproduct of the site will yeld the categorical product of the categories of sheaf, wich is the co-product of the topos...

If I'm not mistaken you obtain a site for the product by taking the product of the two site and constructing a suitable 'product topology' on it...